# Cannot store an array using dask

Tags: numpy, dask, h5py

I am using the following code to create an array and and store the the results sequentially in a hdf5 format. I was checking out the dask documentation, and the suggested to use dask.store to store the arrays generated in a function like mine. However I receive an error: `dask has no attribute store`

My code:

```
import os 
import numpy as np 
import time 
import concurrent.futures 
import multiprocessing
from itertools import product
import h5py
import dask as da


def mean_py(array):
    start_time = time.time() 

    x = array.shape[1] 
    y = array.shape[2] 
    values = np.empty((x,y), type(array[0][0][0]))
    for i in range(x):
        for j in range(y): 
            values[i][j] = ((np.mean(array[:,i,j]))) 
    end_time = time.time() 
    hours, rem = divmod(end_time-start_time, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(rem,60) 
    print("{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:05.2f}".format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds)))

    print(f"{'.'*80}")
    return values 

def generate_random_array():
    a = np.random.randn(120560400).reshape(10980,10980)
    return a


def generate_array(nums):

    for num in range(nums):
        a = generate_random_array()
        f = h5py.File('test_db.hdf5')
        d = f.require_dataset('/data', shape=a.shape, dtype=a.dtype)
        da.store(a, d)


start = time.time() 

generate_array(8)

end = time.time()

print(f'\nTime complete: {end-start:.2f}s\n')
```

Should I use dask for such a a task, or do you recommend to store the results using h5py directly?
Please Ignore the mean_py(array) function. It's for something I want to try out once the data has been produced.

Comment: Without `dask`, `d[...] = a` should be enough.  And in the loop you want to `f.close()`.  Note that this does not do a sequential write.  Each iteration writes a new `a` data to `/data`.

Comment: The `dask` page that documents `store`, defines: `import dask.array as da`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Sorry that I overlooked the import. I will try this out. Definitely very helpful! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you're currently doing this

```
import dask as da
```

When you probably meant to do this

```
import dask.array as da
```